# Consume RSS feed XML and display information

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, feed

I have to consume a feed XML (RSS) in my Windows Phone 7 application and display those information in a `ListBox`.

Following way I tried to read the content in XML feed:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {            
          client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/recenteqsww/catalogs/eqs7day-M2.5.xml"), "usgs");
  }
```

Can someone please guide me how to proceed to get the XML info and to display them as ListBox items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do two things:

1. Download the feed XML from the URL you have there
2. Parse the XML and process the resulting XML document

The following code shows how to do it:

(`GetFeed` does part 1, `handleFeed` does part 2, `button1_Click` is the click handler which starts the feed download when the user clicks a button.)

```
// this method downloads the feed without blocking the UI;
// when finished it calls the given action
public void GetFeed(Action<string> doSomethingWithFeed)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/recenteqsww/catalogs/eqs7day-M2.5.xml");
    request.BeginGetResponse(
        asyncCallback =>
        {
            string data = null;

            using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asyncCallback))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => doSomethingWithFeed(data));
        }
        , null);
}

// this method will be called by GetFeed once the feed has been downloaded
private void handleFeed(string feedString)
{
    // build XML DOM from feed string
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(feedString);

    // show title of feed in TextBlock
    textBlock1.Text = doc.Element("rss").Element("channel").Element("title").Value;
    // add each feed item to a ListBox
    foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("item"))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item.Element("title").Value);
    }

    // continue here...
}

// user clicks a button -> start feed download
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GetFeed(handleFeed);
}
```

Most error checking is omitted for brevity. Some information about what XML elements to expect has [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). The code for downloading the XML file is based on [this excellent blog post](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Data-Access-Strategies-HttpWebRequest.aspx) about using `HttpWebRequest`.